# How to pass complex object in RedirectToPage

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I need to add redirection to page with certain parameters. Query string must looks like:

> PageName?ComplexObject.Property1=true&ComplexObject.Property2=5

I trying to do that by passing complex object to `RedirectToPage` method:

```
public IActionResult OnPostRedirectToPage()
{
    return RedirectToPage(
        "PageName", 
        new
        {
            ComplexObject = new
            {
                Property1=true,
                Property2=5
            }
        });
}
```

But I get query string that looks like:

> PageName?ComplexObject=*ComplexObjectTypeFullName*

The problem is that `RedirectToPage` just calls `ToString` method for every object property. How to change this behavior and make redirection to page with properties names from my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decide to create `RedirectToPageResult` directly and it helps:

```
return new RedirectToPageResult("PageName")
{
    RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        { "ComplexObject.Property1", true },
        { "ComplexObject.Property2", 5 }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What most methods like `ResirectToPage()` do is calling `ToString()` methods of the non-primitive types. In this case you need to override your `ComplexObject` class's `ToString()` method like

```
public override string ToString(){
    return $"ComplexObject.Property1={Property1}&ComplexObject.Property2={Property2}";
}
```

But why do you need something like that. You can just get the properties individually and set them on the method u use?

Comment: I need it for property binding. I have a common page with property `ComplexObject`.  I thought about this solution, but I want to find more accurate way.